# Office 365 Export proxy addresses from a file of users

Tags: powershell, office365

Hello I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
user1@domain.com
user2@domain.com
user3@domain.com
```

I have been trying to export aliases for each of these users like this:

```
Import-CSV -Path .\users.txt | ForEach-Object {Get-Mailbox | Select-Object DisplayName,@{Name=“EmailAddresses”;Expression={$_.EmailAddresses | Where-Object {$_ -LIKE “SMTP:*”}}} | Sort | Format-List}
```

However it appears this script is exporting user info for all users for each line of users. Seems like a simple thing I'm trying to do however I'm not understanding where I've gone wrong here. Any assistance greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe try ForEach ( $item in Import-CSV -Path .\users.txt ) { Get-Mailbox ...

Comment: I have the same results here. It still spits out all the users in the tenant.